# Не получается отладить код с точкой останова в XCode

Tags: отладка, xcode, macos, c++

Добрый день, форумчане!

Я только начинаю программировать под MAC и работать со средой разработки XCode. Прочитала несколько мануалов по отладке, посмотрела видео, и всё-таки не выходит. Ставлю в коде точку останова, как я поняла, по умолчанию среда создаёт точку останова exception breakpoint. А я работаю с библиотекой, код которой написала сама и которую хочу отладить в тестовом проекте. Библиотека и тестовый проект лежат в одном решении. Однако почему-то я не могу отладить проект. Каждый раз среда говорит, что построение было успешно завершено и не заходит ни в одну точку останова.

Раньше я писала программы в Visual Studio и привыкла, что при запуске программы, в которой есть точка останова, компилятор доходит до точки, и далее можно по шагам отслеживать выполнение программы.

Совпадают ли в этом плане механизмы отладки в Visual Studio на платформе Windows и в среде XCode на платформе MAC OS.

Буду рада подробному ответу.

Comment: Может быть, ваша библиотека просто не вызывается?

Comment: Библиотека открывается с помощью функции dlopen().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблемы были, во-первых, в коде библиотеки, там были ошибки. Во-вторых, нельзя отладить динамическую библиотеку. Вышла из положения созданием консольного приложения, туда поместила все файлы библиотеки, хорошенько отладила. Только потом подключила собранную библиотеку к тестовому приложению - и всё сработало. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Все работает так же, как и в Visual Studio, убедитесь, что код, который вы отлаживаете, реально отрабатывает, например, подставьте breakpoint в самое начало исполнения библиотеки, то есть там, где код точно срабатывает.

---

К тому же поясните, о какой библиотеке идет речь? .framework или static library или это же это embeded .xcodeproj, который собирается динамически в static library?